# iOS recurring Alarm - Push notification

Tags: swift, alarm, localnotification

In my app, i need to set alarm when the user receives a push notification.And it should stop when the user reads the notification. How to achieve it?

Comment: You should be using Local Notifications instead of push notifications in such cases

Comment: Local notification is not working for me. Could you please explain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notification Extension to trigger an alarm.But you cannot have to repeatedly alert between the user reads the notification.It is possible you can notify sound for 30seconds.